# Do I owe Congestion Charge for London?

Tags: london, driving, tolls

I travelled to 162 City Rd, London EC1V 2PD from N13 5LF yesterday, 9 February 2016. Do I have to pay congestion charge?

Answer (score 8):

It depends on where exactly you drove and where you parked, but you probably do not need to pay. It is quite clearly signed when you enter the Congestion Charge Zone; if you did not pass these signs, you should not have to pay.

The address that was your destination is right on the edge of the Congestion Charge Zone, you can enter the address here to determine which roads you drove on:
https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/congestion-charge/congestion-charge-zone?intcmp=2055

The Ring Road (including City Road) itself is not within the zone.

I believe if you entered the zone at all with your car then you will have to pay.